# Remove '@NA' from Matlab Table

Tags: matlab, data-cleaning, matlab-table

I have the following code to clean table data of error terms:

```
    errorTerms={'@NA', '#NA', 'ActiveX VT_ERROR: '};
inputData=readtable(inputFile,'TreatAsEmpty',errorTerms);
```

However '@NA' terms remain.

I can get rid of them in this way:

```
inputData.GICS1=strrep(inputData.GICS1,'@NA','NaN');
```

But this requires several independent loops as I have many tables of different sizes.
Is there a more elegant way to import this data as tables? Or clean it?

The data looks like this:

> ```
> Id Avg GICS1
> a 3.0 @NA
> b 5.6 Consumer Staples
> c 4.8 Materials
> d 3.1 Health Care
> e 1.6 Energy
> f 9.3 @NA
> g 8.5 Industrials
> h 7.0 Consumer Discretionary
> ```

Comment: From the docs, TreatAsEmpty only applies to numeric columns. Are the '@NA' entries in numeric columns?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? I cannot reproduce this behavior using a [custom `.csv` file](http://pastebin.com/ivZxzr8P) on R2015a. I doing `readtable('tab.csv','TreatAsEmpty',{'@NA', '#NA', 'ActiveX VT_ERROR: '});` and am getting `NaN` for all cases listed in the cell. What do you want to appear in the the table in the cases of invalid values?

Comment: Some columns are numeric others are strings. I am using 2015a and importing from xlsx rather than csv. Will need it to remain xlsx as different tabs represent different tables and I cannot have tabs with a csv.

Comment: It would be immensely useful if you provided an example that reproduces your issue.

Comment: The above code is my code as it is. I have added a copy of the excel data.

Comment: Do you want to transform `'@NA'` to `NaN` or do you want to remove the row entirely?

Comment: Transform to NaN please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`varfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html) to go through your table columns and apply a regex to each column using [`regexrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) and your `errorTerms` array:

```
inputData = readtable('test.xlsx');

errorTerms = {'@NA', '#NA', 'ActiveX VT_ERROR: '};
expression = sprintf('(%s)', strjoin(errorTerms, '|'));

% Explicit loop
varnames = inputData.Properties.VariableNames;
for ii = 1:length(varnames)
    try
        inputData.(varnames{ii}) = regexprep(inputData.(varnames{ii}), expression, 'NaN');
    catch err
        switch err.identifier
            case 'MATLAB:UndefinedFunction'
                % Do nothing, skip loop iteration
            otherwise
                rethrow(err)
        end
    end
end

% % Only works for string data
% varnames = inputData.Properties.VariableNames;
% inputData = varfun(@(x) regexprep(x, expression, 'NaN'), inputData);
% inputData.Properties.VariableNames = varnames; % Variable names overwritten by varfun, set them back
```

---

Edit: I have added a [`try/catch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) block to account for mixed data types in your columns. I will caveat that this is a fairly greedy implementation, a more robust method would be to compare the error message to make sure `regexprep` is what is causing the issue but I'm lazy.

Comment: Thanks. Although I get the error: Undefined function 'regexprep' for input arguments of type 'double'. When I apply your code. Could this be because I have other columns that contain numbers? Sorry I do not mention above and only inserted a reduced example of the excel data for space

Comment: The sample data you provided only contains strings. If you have mixed data types this won't work.